# If $G$ is a group, and $a, b \in G$, show that if $a^{-1} b^{2} a = b^{3}$ and $a^{2} = 1$, then $b^{5} = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I've been playing with this one for a while and I can't seem to get any closer to the solution. Does anyone have any suggestions or a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $a^{-1}=a$ since $a^2=1$, so $ab^2a=b^3$, from your first equation.

Now, $ab^6a = (ab^2 a)(ab^2 a)(a b^2 a) =b^3b^3b^3=b^9$, or $ab^6a=b^9$, from which it follows that $b^6=ab^9a$ (multiplying the equation by $a$ both on the left and the right).

Also, $b^6=b^3b^3=(ab^2a)(ab^2a)=ab^4a$, so
 $$ ab^9 a = ab^4 a, $$
and it follows that $b^5=1$, as wanted.